# db_query - Get all nid in more than one nodetype

Tags: 6, database, security

This is a simple query , but i really dont know why its not working. I think the problem is with single quote used!

```
$type = array('node_type_1', 'node_type_2', 'node_type_3');
$placeholders = db_placeholders($type, 'text');
$query = "SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = %d AND type IN ($placeholders) AND status = 1 ORDER BY nid DESC";
$result = pager_query($query, 10, 0, NULL, $user->uid, $type);
```

It tried this also

```
$result = pager_query($query, 10, 0, NULL, $user->uid, implode(', ',$type);
```

I am getting error

```
warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to use `db_placeholders()` with `page_query()` is shown in [taxonomy_select_nodes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6). In your case, the code should be the following one.

```
$type = array('node_type_1', 'node_type_2', 'node_type_3');
$placeholders = db_placeholders($type, 'text');
$args = array_merge(array($user->uid), $type);

$query = "SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = %d AND type IN ($placeholders) AND status = 1 ORDER BY nid DESC";
$result = pager_query($query, 10, 0, NULL, $args);
```